# Choosing a renderer - difference between default and J2D?

Tags: processing, antialiasing, renderer

The Processing [size() documentation](http://processing.org/reference/size_.html) says:

> In addition to the default renderer, other renderers are: P2D, P3D, PDF

So what's the difference between **Default** and **J2D**?

There used to be `JAVA2D`, `P2D`, `P3D` and `OPENGL` before v2 and I believe that `P3D` is now just `OPENGL`.

This link has some relevant info [Life Saving Tips For Processing](http://amnonp5.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/25-life-saving-tips-for-processing/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 4 render modes in Processing 2.0:

- default ("slow" but very accurate 2D render mode)
- P2D (OPENGL, faster but less accurate 2D render mode)
- P3D (OPENGL and well, 3D)
- PDF (for PDF output)

default | P2D | P3D

[image: default]
[image: P2D]
[image: P3D]

Code I used to create these images:

```
void setup() {
  //size(200, 200);
  //size(200, 200, P2D);
  size(200, 200, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  background(153);
  strokeWeight(10);
  ellipse(100, 100, 100, 100);
}
```

You can find a more detailed explanation including a guide on choosing the right mode at [What is P3D?](http://www.processing.org/tutorials/p3d/)

Comment: Thanks @kraftner. What exactly does "accuracy" mean in relation to render mode. Will this effect how pixelated a circle would appear or anti-aliasing for example?

Comment: That is a good example. You should easily see this if you just try with a simple sketch.

Comment: Thanks I will do when I get home. The reason I was asking is because I have a sketch where it looks like anti-aliasing is creeping in with the default (i.e. none specified) 'accurate' render mode. Is there anything else I can do to combat this?

Comment: Also is there any other issues I should be aware of using OPENGL such as rendering differently on different systems?

Comment: Concerning anti-aliasing this should be a different question, but have a look at [smooth()](http://processing.org/reference/smooth_.html)

Comment: I have a smooth(8) call after size() but am still seeing artifacts on a number of lines, looks like I will have to work backwards to find out where the issue creeps in.

Comment: Just to be clear, the render mode does not impact anti-aliasing but the default renderer will result in less accurate/pixelated lines.